# Easy way to distinguish between Angular's path and matrix parameters from a route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Angular's `ActivatedRoute` class has a `params` Observable that emits the path and matrix params on the activated route. So if I have the following route:

```
{
  path: 'foo/:id',
  component: Foo
}
```

Navigating between `foo/1` and `foo/2` causes this Observable to emit `{id: 1}` and `{id: 2}` accordingly. If I navigate between `foo/1;fruit=apple` and `foo/1;fruit=orange`, the Observable emits `{fruit: 'apple'}` and `{fruit: 'orange'}` accordingly.

**In my case, I really only care about path param emissions**. Is there an easy way to somehow filter out the matrix params or only subscribe to the path params through some other means? My only idea thus far is to either (1) parse the full URL to distinguish between the types of params or (2) parse the URLSegments of the route for the path param changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `ActivatedRoute.snapshot.url`?  The `url` property is of type `UrlSegment[]` and `UrlSegment.parameters` should give you the matrix parameters.

Comment: Yeah, it only gives me the matrix params of the `UrlSegment`s of that specific route, not all inherited matrix params. In my app, `paramInheritanceStrategy` is set to `'always'` so my activated route inherits the matrix params of all parent routes. Thus, I'll still need to traverse up the route tree to grab all matrix params and "filter them out" of `ActivatedRoute.params`.

Comment: I see... maybe you could check out `@ngrx/router-state`, it may have such feature. If not, it might be worth raising a feature request.